# Game Crashes when adding to array or linker List 

Tags: java, android, arraylist, linked-list, andengine

So I'm having an issue with adding to an ArrayList or a Linked List (tried both, but each crash the same). I'm working off of an AndEngine tutorial (Jimvaders, which worked fine), but when adapting it to my own project, it isn't working properly. Basically, when I shoot a bullet, it gets added to a list of bullets, but in my project, trying to touch the ArrayList or LinkedList, located in the GameScene, from the playerChar class causes the whole game to crash. I haven't even done anything with the list yet, so it's just the act of adding my PlayerBullet to the list that is causing the problem as far as I can tell.

GameScene:

```
public ArrayList<PlayerBullet> bulletList;
```

in my PlayerChar class

```
public void shoot(int playerFacing) { //TODO

    GameScene scene = (GameScene) BaseActivity.getSharedInstance().getCurrentScene();
    float shootX = 2;

    PlayerBullet b =(PlayerBullet)PlayerBulletPool.sharedBulletPool().obtainPoolItem();

    if (playerFacing == -1){
        shootX *= -1;
    }
    else{
        shootX += this.getWidth();
    }


    b.sprite.setPosition(this.getX() + shootX, this.getY()+(this.getHeight()/2));
    MoveXModifier mod = new MoveXModifier(0.5f, b.sprite.getX(), mCamera.getCenterX() + (mCamera.getWidth()*playerFacing));

    b.sprite.setVisible(true);
    b.sprite.detachSelf();
    scene.attachChild(b.sprite);
    //Log.v("checkin", "works to here");
    scene.bulletList.add(b);//<---------Crashes Here, works fine if this line is commented out

    //Log.v("checkin", "still working?");
    b.sprite.registerEntityModifier(mod);

}
```

Any insight would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Have you properly initialized the bulletList array? You have `public ArrayList<PlayerBullet> bulletList;` but you never create the new array. For example, you may need to say `public ArrayList<PlayerBullet> bulletList = new ArrayList<PlayerBullet>();`

Comment: Does it crash with an error thrown? If so, could you show us the error?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to initialize it. Fixed the problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you've got a NullPointerException, although it would help if you'd told us. This line:

```
scene.bulletList.add(b);
```

requires that both `scene` and `scene.bulletList` are non-null. We can tell that `scene` is non-null, but I suspect that `scene.bulletList`is null - where do you *think* you're initializing it?

(As an aside, I would strongly advise you to avoid public variables. I would probably put an `addBullet` method into `GameScene` - and probably make the type of the now-private `bulletList` variable `List<PlayerBullet>`... only specify `ArrayList<E>` when initializing the variable.)

Comment: Thank you. This was the problem. I had forgotten to initialize it. IT has been a while since I've used Java, typing the variables sometimes makes me think I've already established what it is supposed to be.